# Error al momento de hacer deploy en github pages con mi proyecto de Angular: .nojekyll file could not be created

Tags: github-pages

estoy tratando de hacer un deploy en github pages, donde quiero subir mi portafolio; los pasos que hice fueron estos:

- npm i angular-cli-ghpages (funcionó sin problemas)
- ng deploy --base-href=https://brianpadim20.github.io/portafolio/ (me arrojó un error)

El error al momento de hacer el deploy es este:

```
❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
.nojekyll file could not be created. ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'Portafoliobps\portafolio\dist\portafolio\browser\.nojekyll'
```

Intento crear en dist\portafolio la carpeta browser porque no está, y dentro de esta carpeta agregar el .nojekyll, sin embargo al momento de hacer el deploy no me funciona; puesto que elimina esta carpeta y sigue sin cargar mi página en githubpages... Agradecería cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.